# Why my linked list insertion function gets segmentation fault when inputing strings with scanf?

Tags: c, string, function, linked-list

I am a algorithm student trying to implement a linked list with words, in a way that it is in alphabetical order. The problems is that when I get a input with scanf and pass it to the function it gets segmentation fault. I have tried passing directly the strings and it worked fine.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct NOH {
    char *palavra; 
    struct NOH *next; 
    struct NOH *prev; 
}NOH;

typedef struct LISTA {
    NOH *head;
}LISTA;

void *cria_lista(){
    LISTA *new_lista = (LISTA*) malloc(sizeof(LISTA));
    new_lista -> head = NULL;

    return new_lista;
}

void insere_lista(LISTA *lista, char *palavra){
    NOH *new_node = (NOH*) malloc(sizeof(NOH));
    new_node -> palavra = palavra;

    if(lista -> head == NULL){
        lista -> head = new_node;
        new_node -> next = NULL;
        new_node -> prev = NULL;
    } else {

        if(strcmp(palavra, lista -> head -> palavra) < 0){ 
            new_node -> prev = NULL;
            new_node -> next = lista -> head;
            lista -> head -> prev = new_node;
            lista -> head = new_node;
        } else {

            NOH *aux = lista -> head;
            while(strcmp(palavra, aux -> palavra) > 0 && aux -> next != NULL)
                aux = aux -> next;

            if(aux -> next == NULL && strcmp(palavra, aux -> palavra) > 0){ 
                new_node -> next = NULL;
                new_node -> prev = aux;
                aux -> next = new_node;
            } else { //se tiver que ser inserido no meio
                new_node -> next = aux;
                new_node -> prev = aux -> prev;
                aux -> prev -> next = new_node;
                aux -> prev = new_node;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printa_lista(LISTA *lista){
    NOH *aux = lista -> head;
    if(aux == NULL)
        printf("lista vazia!\n");
    else {
        while(aux -> next != NULL){
            printf("%s -> ", aux -> palavra);
            aux = aux -> next;
        }
        printf("%s\n", aux -> palavra);
    }
}

int main(){
    char word[100];

    LISTA *L = cria_lista();

    scanf("%s", word);
    insere_lista(L, word); //using "teste" as word
    printa_lista(L);

    scanf("%s", word); 
    insere_lista(L, word); //using "testee" as word
    printa_lista(L);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried using gdb to find where the segmentation fault is and this was the verdict:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555498a in insere_lista (lista=0x555555756260, 
    palavra=0x7fffffffde20 "testee") at lista_encadeada.c:51
51                  aux -> prev -> next = new_node;
```

Using the following code as the main seems to work:

```
int main(){
    char word[100];  
    LISTA *L = cria_lista();

    insere_lista(L, "macaco");
    printa_lista(L);

    insere_lista(L, "avestruz");
    printa_lista(L);

    insere_lista(L, "elefante");
    printa_lista(L);

    insere_lista(L, "cavalo");
    printa_lista(L);

    insere_lista(L, "zebra");
    printa_lista(L);

    insere_lista(L, "hipopotamo");
    printa_lista(L);

    return 0;
}
```

I am brazilian by the way, so sorry for my english and for my code beeing in portuguese, if it is too much trouble I can try to rewrite it in english.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be used with spaces around them.
Writing `ptr -> member` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `ptr->member`.

Comment: I suggest you run the program under a debugger, and examine the value of `aux->prev` before the statement that gets the error.

Comment: Since you don't copy the data, all nodes will end up with the same word value — the one that was entered last. Fixing that is a step or two further down the line; you need to get the basics working first when it doesn't matter what the data is.  It may be significant that the 'working' code has separate values for each string — whereas the failing code does not.  But I think the two are unrelated (but I've not studied the code hard yet).

Comment: The simple solution to that problem is `new_node -> palavra = strdup(palavra);`

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jonathan Leffler I will try to change my code as you said. And thank you too Barmar, your "simple solution" did work fine. I shall use a debugger as you said.

Comment: Hint: when the list only has one node, its `next` and `prev` pointers are both `NULL`. So `aux->prev` will be `NULL`.